# On EC2, why do I need individual EBS volumes for journal, log, and data?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

According to [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/#deploy-mongodb-ec2) MongoDB tutorial which explains how to manually deploy MongoDB on EC2, one of the steps states that you should have:

"Individual PIOPS EBS volumes for data (1000 IOPS), journal (250 IOPS), and log (100 IOPS)."

Why do I need individual EBS volumes for journal, log, and data?
Can I just combine these into one EBS volume?

Comment: The information presented there may be based in part on the mechanical hard drive EBS service offering, which has been somewhat superseded by SSD EBS volumes.  SSD EBS volumes automatically provide a certain number of IOPS *per GB*, creating a disincentive to splitting up data this way, and contradicting conventional wisdom, which was rotating disk centric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB team may have experienced that IOPS needs for data is highest, log is the lowest and journal is somewhere in the middle. Although I am less familiar with MongoDB, I suspect that some of the reasons why they *might* be suggesting different EBS volumes include:

- cost saving: provision right amount of IOPS based on needs will save $. If it was all on a single partition, you'd use maximum IOPS of 1000 and end up paying more
- snapshot: you could snapshot data at a different (more frequent?) interval
- contention: data, journaling and logging will not contend with each other if they are on different volumes
- scaling: you could scale data volume separately from journal and log volumes
- risk reduction: if data volume has troubles you could restore from backup and reapply journal (I assume you can), and analyze at logs too

Answer (score 0):

The reason for separating your deployment storage across 3 volumes is that database journal files and log files are sequential in nature, and as such, have different access patterns compared to data files. Separating data files from journal and/or log files, particularly with a write intensive workload, will provide an increase in performance by reducing I/O contention. Depending on your workload, and if you are experiencing high I/O wait times, you may be able to benefit from separate disks for your data files, journal, and log files.

The answer was taken from https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/maximizing-mongodb-performance-on-aws